# How to login compute module via serial port?

Tags: serial-console, compute-module-3

I tried to login to compute module 3 io board from a USB serial port in my PC, but PUTTY just hangs there.

Following procedures have been made:

1. `raspi-config` -> interface options -> serial port -> say yes to login shell over serial.
2. Reboot CM3.
3. Installed driver for USB serial connector on my PC.
4. Connect RX line (white) to GPIO 14 (UART0 TX), TX line (green) to GPIO 15 (UART0 RX), ground line (black) to a nearby GND pin. For the 3.3v line (red), I tried either connect it to GPIO27 or just hang it. The meaning of pins are referred from [Compute Module IO Pins](https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-hardware/raspberry-pi-compute-module/compute-module-io-pins)
5. Open `PUTTY` in my PC, connect to COM3 with 115200 baud rate.

After all these works, PUTTY just show me a flashing cursor. It neither show command prompt, nor respond to my keyboard.

Comment: What's the voltage levels of the USB serial connector?

Comment: @Ghanima 3.3 Volt

Comment: Are you sure COM3 is the right port? The problem could also be a broken USB-to-serial adapter or faulty drivers.

Comment: @WesleyChalmers Yes it is the right port, I read it from device manager: Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM3)